# Embedded: OMAP3 EVM boot arguments

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, bootloader, u-boot, omap

I'm a beginner. I'm using `OMAP3 EVM`. Currently, I'm able to boot via `NFS`. But, I want it to be from `SD card`. I removed the `boot.scr` file while changing it to SD boot. It was booting properly. But, after the line `'Uncompressing Linux...'` it waits for some time and then  file system gets loaded directly and asks for login. The so many lines of initialization logs which used to come after the line `'Uncompressing Linux...'` are completely missing. But, the root file system is fully loaded and I'm able to use it as I did previously. So, I tried making the boot.scr file by removing the nfs related arguments alone.

The `boot.scr` commands previously,

```
setenv bootargs 'mem=128M console=ttyS0,115200n8 noinitrd rw rootfstype=ext3 ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.15.3:/home/mistral/nfsroot,nolock'
setenv bootcmd 'mmc init; fatload mmc 0 0x80000000 uImage; bootm 0x80000000'
fatload mmc 0 0x80000000 uImage
bootm 0x80000000
```

The `boot.scr` commands now,

```
setenv bootcmd 'mmc init; fatload mmc 0 0x80000000 uImage; bootm 0x80000000'
fatload mmc 0 0x80000000 uImage
bootm 0x80000000
```

I haven't modified the `uEnv.txt`. It's contents are,

```
bootargs=console=ttyS0,115200n8 mem=256M root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootfstype=ext3 rootwait init=/linuxrc ip=off
bootcmd=mmc rescan ; fatload mmc 0 81000000 uImage ; bootm 81000000
uenvcmd=bootd
```

Now, it has completely stopped booting after the line `'Uncompressing Linux...'`.
Please guide me in where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You can ask your question here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/beagleboard , this is more active for beagleboard and stuffs :)

Comment: If the Kernel is loaded properly, then I'd suggest making sure that S0 (in console=ttyS0,115200n8) is the right console. I have a beagleboard and I remember I had to change that (O1 or O3, don't remember exactly).

Comment: @srd Thanks. I use `minicom` and initially I configured it to S0. Only then it was displaying the boot logs. But, kernel related details alone are not getting displayed. With NFS it was ok only. With SDCard only, it is like this :(

Comment: @Gomu Are the kernel images loaded from the NFS and the SD card the same ? The Kerenl may be configured such that it overrides the bootloader's boot parameters (and hence, override the console parameter passed from the bootloader). Try coping the Kernel image from the NFS to the SD card.

Comment: @srd Actually the root file system alone was in the NFS. The boot.scr, mlo, uboot and uImage were in SD Card only during NFS booting. So, they are the same only. What else can I try? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `/dev/ttyS0` that you set in minicom is the serial port on your PC and **NOT** the OMAP EVM board.

Refer to the original bootargs or release-notes of user-guide to determine the proper value of the `console` variable for your EVM board and BSP release.

In addition to specifying the proper `console=` option,

- pass the **`earlyprintk`** param
- do NOT pass the **`silent`** param

on the kernel cmd-line (bootargs).